# Python 3 ... changing from using a dict to json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I had my configuration in a dictionary that was imported in the form of (note this is an example, and not my actual code):

myconfig.py

```py
CONFIG_DICT = {
  'EMAIL1'             : 'fred.flintstone@gmail.com',
  'EMAIL2'             : '',
  'EMAIL3'             : '',
  'MIN'                : 21,
  'MAX'                : 28,
  'MAPPING'     : [("11", "AA"), ("22", "BB"), ("33", "CC"),("44","DD"),("55", "EE")],
 }
```

I would access that in my code with something like this:

```py
    import myConfig.py
    email1 = myConfig.CONFIG_DICT.get( "EMAIL1" )
    email2 = myConfig.CONFIG_DICT.get( "EMAIL2" )
    email3 = myConfig.CONFIG_DICT.get( "EMAIL3" )
    min = float(myConfig.CONFIG_DICT.get( "MIN" ))
    max = float(myConfig.CONFIG_DICT.get( "MAX" ))
    mapping = myConfig.CONFIG_DICT.get(  "MAPPING" )

    def findName(ID):
        for i in range(len(mapping)):
            if mapping[i][0] == ID:
                return(mapping[i][1])
        return("Unmapped")
```

That would all work quite well.
I’ve now moved to putting all of these into a JSON file (for other reasons).   It all works OK apart from the 2D array

Sample code:

```py
    with open('myConfig.json', 'r+') as f:
        json_text = f.read() # for dictionary config
        f.seek(0)

        # Decode the JSON string into a Python dictionary.
        myConfig = json.loads(json_text)

    email1 = vchConfig["EMAIL1"]
    email2 = vchConfig["EMAIL2"]
    email3 = vchConfig["EMAIL3"]
    min = float(vchConfig["MIN"])
    max = float(vchConfig["MAX"])
    mapping = vchConfig[ "MAPPING"]
```

Now when I try to run, I get: `KeyError: 0`

I've tried various format changes in the json file, but I've gone around in circles

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message

Comment: You should add your json version of config as well...

Comment: Sorry, thought I had included the json version of config .... I've included it in my answer below now (shows I'm having a bad day)

Comment: ForceBru ... that was all I got (although I think my exception catching picked it up ... my bad)

Answer (score -1):

Ah ... I must have been stupid (I did say I was going around in circles - sorry)

It needed to be like this:

```
    "MAPPING": [
        [
            "11",
            "AA"
        ],
        [
            "22",
            "BB"
        ],
        [
            "33",
            "CC"
        ],
        [
            "44",
            "DD"
        ],
        [
            "55",
            "EE"
        ]
    ]
```

I originally had it as:

```
    "SENSOR_MAPPING": [
        {"11", "AA"},
        {"22", "BB"},
        {"33", "CC"},
        {"44", "DD"},
        {"55", "EE"}
    ]
```

I'm sure I'd tried that combo and it wasn't working either, so in the end, I just dumped the DICT out to a json file to see what format it gave, and used that.

Sorry, if I wasted anyone's time.